# How to change the permission of my internal cd/dvd drive?

Tags: permissions, root, cd-drive

I decided to build my own gui (ubuntu server, openbox and stuff).

I am having a permissions problem with my cd drive. When I try to mount it with user privileges it tells me that I'm not allowed.

I can then mount it as root, and can see the content in the root window, but as a normal user i'm still not allowed to view the contents.

So my question here is, how can i configure it in a way that it mounts my cd/dvd's ALWAYS with my reading permissions?

sudo df -h :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              19G  6.5G   12G  37% /
udev                  995M  4.0K  995M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 402M  528K  401M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                 1004M  4.0K 1004M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda4             420G  306G   92G  77% /home
/dev/sda5              20G   16K   20G   1% /windows
/dev/sr0              6.1G  6.1G     0 100% /media/BIOSHOCK
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing is to add an entry to /etc/fstab like:

```
/dev/sr0       /media/cdrom       auto        noauto,owner,ro,users  0   0
```

Then you should be able to run

```
mount /media/cdrom
```

as a normal user.  Alternatively, you can pass the uid= and gid= options to mount (when running under sudo) to tell mount who you want to own the mounted filesystem.

```
man mount
```

for more information.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your permissions are not getting set correctly. Here is mine, to compare with yours.  I see I do not have write access. May only be set when a writeable disk is inserted. The key is to have read access to 'world' since your user is not member or root group, like myself.

```
myname@ubuntu:~$ ll /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 2012-03-02 23:58 /dev/sr0

/media/cdrom0:
total 14
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2048 2005-09-01 08:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 2012-02-16 22:21 ..
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 6144 2005-09-01 08:10 50 Bible Class Books (#1)
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2048 2005-09-01 08:10 Bible Class Books (#2)
```

sudo chmod 555 /media/cdrom0   you shouldn't really need to do this, it ought to be automatic.